# Calculating the Lie algebra of $SO(2,1)$

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I am trying to calculate the Lie algebra of the group $SO(2,1)$, realized as

$$SO(2,1)=\{X\in \operatorname{Mat}_3(\mathbb{R}) \,|\, X^t\eta X=\eta, \det(X)=1\},$$ where $$\eta = \left ( \begin{array}{ccc} 1 &0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&-1\end{array}\right ) .$$

But I am a bit unsure as how to procee:, I know that I need to take a curve in $SO(2,1)$ that passes through the identity at 0 and then differentiate at 0 but I am unsure as to what the form of curves in $SO(2,1)$ are?

So do I let $a(t)\in SO(2,1)$ be a curve with $a(0)=1$ so that:

$$a'(0)^t\eta+\eta a'(0)=\eta ?$$

Comment: $SO(2,1)$ is isomorphic to $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$, which has a standard basis, c.f. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sl2-triple

Comment: Your equation should have $0$ on the right hand side since $\eta$ doesn't depend on $t$. Otherwise it's correct. Note that if instead of $\eta$ we would have identity matrix (group $SO(3)$), this equation would be solved by anti-symmetric matrices.

Comment: The equation here is then $A = - \eta A^t \eta$. It's quite simple to solve but as a baby step you can try $SO(1,1)$ with $\eta = {\rm diag}(1, -1)$ first.

Comment: It should be noted that @Neal's statement above is a statement about Lie algebras, not Lie groups. $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ the Lie group is a double cover of (the identity component of) $\text{SO}(2, 1)$ the Lie group. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_group for more.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan this was long enough ago that I don't remember whether I was thinking of the isometries of hyperbolic space or simply forgot \mathfrak. In either case, thank you for the erratum!

Answer (score 13):

We identify the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(2, 1)$ with the tangent space $T_1 SO(2, 1)$ to $SO(2, 1)$ at the identity $1$. As hinted in the question, for any $A \in \mathfrak{so}(2, 1)$ we can pick a curve $a: J \to SO(2, 1)$ such that $a'(0) = A$. (We'll see below that the existence of such curves is all we need, i.e., we don't need to write out curves explicitly.) Then, the characterizing equation of $A$ gives
$$a(t)^T \eta a(t) = \eta,$$
and differentiating with respect to $t$ gives
$$a'(t)^T \eta a(t) + a(t)^T \eta a'(t) = 0$$
(note that the r.h.s. is $0$, not $\eta$). Evaluating at $t = 0$ gives
$$\phantom{(\ast)} \qquad A^T \eta + \eta A = 0. \qquad (\ast)$$
(By the way, up to this point we haven't used the form of $\eta$ yet, so this characterization holds just as well for any nondegenerate bilinear form $\eta$ in any finite dimension.)

Now we can write the Lie algebra explicitly simply working out the (linear) conditions determined by the above characterization. Doing so is just a matter of writing out $(\ast)$ in components, but observe that the form of $\eta$ suggests a natural block decomposition of the Lie algebra. Decompose a general element $A \in \mathfrak{so}(2, 1)$ as
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} W & x \\ y^T & z \end{pmatrix},$$
where $W \in M(2, \mathbb{R})$, $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $z \in \mathbb{R}$. In this block decomposition,
$\eta = \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{I}_2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$
and $(\ast)$ becomes
$$\begin{pmatrix} W^T & y \\ x^T & z\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{I}_2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix} \mathbb{I}_2 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} W & x \\ y^T & z\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}.$$

Writing out separately the equation for each block imposes precisely the conditions
$$W^T = -W, \qquad y = x, \qquad z = 0,$$
so,
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{so}(2, 1)
&= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} W & x \\ x^T & 0\end{pmatrix} : W^T = -W \right\} \\
&= \left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -w & x_1 \\ w & 0 & x_2 \\ x_1 & x_2 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}  \textrm{.}
\end{align}
(Of course, the condition on $W$ is just that $W \in \mathfrak{so}(2, \mathbb{R})$, where the bilinear form on $\mathbb{R}^2$ is just the standard one, i.e., the one with matrix representation $\mathbb{I}_2$.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if what I'm about to write is completely correct, I face the same difficulties with $SU(1,1)$, and this is what I came up with.

First of all because we are working with matrices this means we are embedding $SO(2,1)$ in $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, this is the case if $SO(2,1)$ is a Lie subgroup of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, a general theorem (stated in almost every introductory texts on Lie groups) assures us that every close subgroup of $GL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is a matrix Lie group.

Suppose we proved that $SO(2,1)$ is a  a closed subgroup of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$, thus there is an embedding $i$ of $SO(2,1)$ in $i(SO(2,1))\subset GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$.

This embedding is such that the exponential function $\exp:\mathfrak{so}(2,1)\longrightarrow SO(2,1)$ of $SO(2,1)$ is the usual exponential of a matrix in $i(SO(2,1))\subset GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ (this can be proved).

From this it follows that the Lie algebra $i(\mathfrak{so}(2,1))$ of $i(SO(2,1))$ is characterized by the condition:

$$
A: exp(tA)\in i(SO(2,1))\;\;\;\forall t
$$
therefore from the defining condition of $SO(2,1)$ we get:

$$
(exp(tA))^{T}\eta \exp(tA)=\eta
$$

Then:

$$
\frac{d (exp(tA))^{T}\eta \exp(tA)}{dt}\left|_{t=0}\right.=\frac{d\eta}{dt}\left|_{t=0}\right.
$$

Which means:

$$
A^{T}\eta + A\eta=0
$$

Moreover we can use the general properties of the exponential $\exp$ of a matrix:

$$
det(\exp(A))=\exp(Tr(A))
$$
in order to obtain:

$$
Tr(A)=0
$$

Thus the Lie algebra of $i(SO(2,1))$ is the set of matrices such that:

$$
Tr(A)=0 \;\;\;\mbox{ and } \;\;\; A^{T}\eta + A\eta=0
$$

If you want to use the curves in $SO(2,1)$ you have to find a coordinate system on $SO(2,1)$, in order to explicitely write the curve $a(t)$ and calculate its tangent vectors at the identity.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add another answer to the very nice answers above.

First recall the definition of the Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group:

Let $G$ be a matrix Lie group. The  Lie algebra of $G$, denoted
$\mathfrak{g}$, is the set of all matrices $X$ such that $e^{tX}$ is in $G$ for all real numbers
$t$.That is, the Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group $G$ is
$
\mathfrak{g}=\{ X\in M_n(\mathbb{C}) : ~ e^{tX} \in G, ~\text{for all}~ t\in \mathbb{R} \} \subseteq M_n(\mathbb{C}).
$

We're interested in finding the Lie algebra of the generalized special orthogonal group $\mathrm{SO}(n;k)$, which is defined as follows: $
\mathrm{SO}(n;k) = \{ A \in M_{n+k}(\mathbb{R}) ~|~A^{tr} g A = g ~~\text{and}~ \det(A)=1 \},
$
where
$
g=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
I_n & 0 \\
0 & -I_k
\end{array}
\right).
$

One can prove without too much trouble that if $G$ is a subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}(n, \mathbb{R})$, then the Lie algebra of $G$ must consist
entirely of real matrices. With this in mind, we'll compute the Lie algebra in question in the following proposition.

Proposition.
The Lie algebra of the real symplectic group $\mathrm{SO}(n; k)$ is given by
$
\{ X\in M_{n+k}(\mathbb{R}): ~g X^{tr} g = -X ~~\text{and}~\mathrm{trace}( X)=0\}.$
It is often called the  special generalized orthogonal  algebra and denoted $\mathfrak{so}(n;k)$.

Proof. Let $X$ be in $\mathfrak{so}(n;k)$ (as noted above, $X$ must be a real matrix). Then, $e^{tX}$ is in $\mathrm{SO}(n;k)$ for all real $t$ so that

$
\begin{array}{llllllllll}
& (e^{tX})^{tr} g e^{tX} &=&g,\\
\text{which implies} & (e^{tX^{tr}}) g e^{tX} &=&g,\\
\text{which implies} & g^{-1} (e^{tX^{tr}}) g e^{tX} &=&I,\\
\text{which implies} & (e^{t g^{-1}X^{tr}g})  e^{tX} &=&I,\\
\text{which implies} & (e^{t g^{-1}X^{tr}g})   &=&e^{-tX}.
\end{array}
$

Differentiating the last equation at $t=0$ yields $g^{-1} X^{tr} g = -X$. This also implies $\mathrm{trace}(X)=\mathrm{trace}(-X)$, so that $\mathrm{trace}(X)=0$. Further, since
$g^{-1} =g$, we have $gX^{tr} g = -X$.  Hence, $\mathfrak{so}(n;k)\subseteq \{ X\in M_{n+k}(\mathbb{R}): ~g X^{tr} g = -X ~~\text{and}~\mathrm{trace}( X)=0\ \}$.

Now let $X$ be a real $(n+k) \times (n+k)$ traceless matrix such that $g X^{tr} g = -X$.  Since $\mathrm{trace}(X)=0$, then,
$\det(e^{tX})=e^{t\cdot\mathrm{trace}(X)}=1$.  And, since $g^{-1}=g$, $g^{-1} X^{tr} g = -X$ and for all real $t$ we have

$
\begin{array}{llllllllll}
 g^{-1}(e^{tX} )^{tr} g e^{tX} & =&e^{tg^{-1}X^{tr} g} e^{tX}  \\
&=& e^{-tX}e^{tX} \\
&=&I,
%& (e^{tX})^{tr} J e^{tX} &=&J,\\
%\text{if and only if} & (e^{tX^{t}}) J e^{tX} &=&J,\\
%\text{if and only if} & J^{-1} (e^{tX^{t}}) J e^{tX} &=&I,\\
%\text{if and only if} & (e^{t J^{-1}X^{t}J})  e^{tX} &=&I,\\
%\text{if and only if} & (e^{t J X^{t}J})   &=&e^{-tX}.
\end{array}
$

so that $(e^{tX} )^{tr} g e^{tX} =g$, for all real $t$ so that $X\in \mathfrak{so}(n;k)$.
This  implies $ \{ X\in M_{n+k}(\mathbb{R}): ~g X^{tr} g = -X~~\text{and}~\mathrm{trace}( X)=0\ \}\subseteq \mathfrak{so}(n;k)$,
and hence $ \{ X\in M_{n+k}(\mathbb{R}): ~g X^{tr} g = -X ~~\text{and}~\mathrm{trace}( X)=0\ \}= \mathfrak{so}(n;k)$.
$\Box$