# How to compute the Lie group of this Lie algebra?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have this set, let's say $A$,
$$
A=\left\lbrace \begin{pmatrix}
0 & a & b \\
a & 0 & c \\
b & -c & 0
\end{pmatrix}; a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}
\right\rbrace,
$$
which is a sub algebra of the $SL(3,\mathbb{R})$-Lie algebra (because it has trace zero and is closed by brackets). By Lie's third theorem we know that there exists a Lie group, namely $G$, having $A$ as Lie algebra.

My question is, does anyone know what group is that? How to compute $G$?
*I've tried to compute it by exponentiation, but I've got stuck in computations.

Comment: It is easy to see what the Lie algebra is, see this site for a classification in dimension $3$. Then it is not hard to say which Lie groups we can take.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde It looks you haven't placed the link.

Comment: Good opportunity to add the link of my own [lecture notes](https://homepage.univie.ac.at/Dietrich.Burde/papers/burde_70_lie_algebra_course.pdf) on the classification. It is section $1.7$.

Answer (score 1):

Denoting the Lie algebra basis of matrices by $\{x_1,x_2,x_3\}$, according to chosing $a,b,c$ equal to one and the other entries equal to zero, we obtain the following commutating relations:
$$
[x_1,x_2]=x_3,\; [x_1,x_3]=x_2,\;[x_2,x_3]=-x_1.
$$
So we have $[L,L]=L$ and $L=A$ must be isomorphic to either $\mathfrak{so}_3(\Bbb R)$ or $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb R)$.
The Killing form of $L$ is negative definite, so it is the orthogonal Lie algebra. So we have $G\cong SO(3,\Bbb R)$.

On the other hand, the Lie brackets are very similar to the ones of $\mathfrak{so}_{2,1}(\Bbb R)$, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/394478/calculating-the-lie-algebra-of-so2-1), which is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{sl}_2(\Bbb R)$.